# How do I check whether some item of Smarty array matches certain condition

Tags: arrays, if-statement, smarty

I have a code that draws a block which contains some categories.

```
      {if $category->subcategories}
        <div class="well">
          <ul class="list-inline">
            {foreach name=categories from=$category->subcategories item=cat}
              {if $cat->category_id >= 1000}
                <li><a href="catalog/{$cat->url}">{$cat->single_name}</a></li>
              {/if}
            {/foreach}
          </ul>
        </div>
      {/if}
```

Those categories are not shown in a general navigation and I show it only on some parent categories. The problem is that not all of those parent categories have children matching my condition:

```
{if $cat->category_id >= 1000}
```

And on that parent category pages I get empty block:

```
    <div class="well">
      <ul class="list-inline">
      </ul>
    </div>
```

How do I check the array `$category->subcategories` whether it has any categories with `$cat->category_id >= 1000` before I draw `<div class="well">`?

Comment: It's probably best to check this in php before passing the array to smarty. You could just traverse the array and as soon as there is an element with category_id >= 1000, you could set a new attribute to the $category object, e. g. $category->draw = true. In smarty you could modify your condition, for example {if $category->draw}. Alternatively you could write a little smarty plugin that checks the existence of fitting elements on demand.

Comment: That makes sense... Thank you. Now I'm trying to figure out how to modify my `get_categories()` function